# Self-composed gnupg mime-mail displays as attachment rather than inline

Tags: email, mime, gnupg

I have a script that does gpg-encryption of text and mails it out.

I use MacGPG / Apple Mail, which decrypts it fine, but doesn't display the text afterwards and instead displays attachments.

These are the mails i construct, what is wrong with it?

```
...
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 16:01:04 +0200
From: <deleted>
To: <deleted>
Message-ID: <deleted>
Subject: asdf
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/encrypted;
 boundary=4b5784e4-fc05-45bb-9a72-e9070a11423c;
 charset=UTF-8;
 protocol="application/pgp-encrypted"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


--4b5784e4-fc05-45bb-9a72-e9070a11423c
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 16:01:04 +0200
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/pgp-encrypted;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <deleted>

Version: 1

--4b5784e4-fc05-45bb-9a72-e9070a11423c
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 16:01:04 +0200
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
 charset=UTF-8;
 name=msg.asc
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline;
 filename=msg.asc
Content-ID: <deleted>

-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.17 (GNU/Linux)

<PGPDATA>
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----

--4b5784e4-fc05-45bb-9a72-e9070a11423c--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem here is, that the encrypted data contains only plain text and is not a fully compliant RFC822 mail message.

As the PGP/MIME RFC 3156 states under section 4, OpenPGP encrypted data

> Before OpenPGP encryption, the data is written in MIME canonical
>   format (body and headers).

Following is an example of an RFC822 compliant mail message, which should
be processed and displayed as expected.

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=us-ascii

This is only encrypted!
```